# glassfish in IntelliJ is started with wrong encoding

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, glassfish

I have set up my glassfish project according to this guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html

The run configurations are created automatically and as far as I can see they use glassfish's startup-script. 
However, upon startup I can see that these commands are executed:

```
C:\path\glassfish5\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
"C:\path\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "..."
```

Somewhere, somehow, a `Dfile.encoding` parameter got added. I tried setting this exact parameter to "UFT-8" instead in the launch configurations VM-Options, but the resulting commands still look exactly like above, no mention of my UTF-8.

I tried searching where this parameter is set or how to change it or anything regarding this, but I found absolutely nothing. 
Does anyone know how I can make IntelliJ/glassfish startup with UTF-8 encoding instead? As mentioned above, setting VM options in the run-configuration had no effect.